# How to overcome indefinite matrix error (NbClust)?

Tags: cluster-analysis

I'm getting the following error when calling `NbClust()`:

> Error in NbClust(data = ds[, sapply(ds, is.numeric)], diss = NULL, distance = "euclidean", : The TSS matrix is indefinite. There must be too many missing values. The index cannot be calculated.

I've called `ds <- ds[complete.cases(ds),]` just before running NbClust so there's no missing values.

Any idea what's behind this error?

Thanks

Comment: I have reduced the amount of variables substantially and am now faced with the following error: Error in NbClust(data = ds[, sapply(ds, is.numeric)], diss = NULL, distance = "euclidean", : invalid clustering method

Answer (score 6):

I had same issue in my research. 
So, I had mailed to Nadia Ghazzali, who is the package maintainer, and got an answer.
I'll attached my mail and her reply.

my e-mail:

> Dear Nadia Ghazzali.   Hello Nadia. I have some questions about
>   NbClust function in R library. I have tried googling but could not
>   find satisfying answers.   First, I’m so grateful for you to making
>   this awsome R library. It is very helpful for my reasearch.   I tested
>   NbClust function in NbClust library with my own data like below.
>
> ```
> > clust <- NbClust(data, distance = “euclidean”, 
>                    min.nc = 2, max.nc = 10, method = ‘kmeans’, index =”all”)
> ```
>
> But soon, an error has occurred. Error: division by zero! Error in
>   Indices.WBT(x = jeu, cl = cl1, P = TT, s = ss, vv = vv) : object
>   'scott' not found   So, I tried NbClust function line by line and
>   found that some indices, like **CCC, Scott, marriot, tracecovw,
>   tracew, friedman, and rubin**, were not calculated because of object
>   vv = 0.   I’m not very familiar with argebra so I don’t know meaning
>   of eigen value.  But it seems to me that object ss(which is squart of
>   eigenValues) should not be 0 after prodected.
>       So, here is my questions.
>   **I assume that my data is so sparse(a lot of zero values) that sqrt(eigenValues) becomes too small, is that right?** I’m sorry I
>   can’t attach my data but I can attach some part of eigenValues and
>   squarted eigenValues.
>
> ```
> > head(eigenValues)
> [1] 0.039769880 0.017179826 0.007011972 0.005698736 0.005164871 0.004567238
>
> > head(sqrt(eigenValues))
> [1] 0.19942387 0.13107184 0.08373752 0.07548997 0.07186704 0.06758134
> ```
>
> And if my assume is right, what can I do for this problems? Only one
>   way to drop out 7 indices?
>       Thank you for reading and I’ll waiting your reply.   Best regards!

and her reply:

> Dear Hansol,
>
> Thank you for your interest. Yes, your understanding is good.
>   Unfortunately, the seven indices could not be applied.
>
> Best regards,
>
> Nadia Ghazzali

Answer (score 0):

@seni The cause of this error is data related. If you look at the source code of this function,

```
NbClust <- function(data, diss="NULL", distance = "euclidean", min.nc=2, max.nc=15, method = "ward", index = "all", alphaBeale = 0.1)
{
x<-0
min_nc <- min.nc
max_nc <- max.nc
jeu1 <- as.matrix(data)
numberObsBefore <- dim(jeu1)[1]
jeu <- na.omit(jeu1) # returns the object with incomplete cases removed 
nn <- numberObsAfter <- dim(jeu)[1]
pp <- dim(jeu)[2]
TT <- t(jeu)%*%jeu   
sizeEigenTT <- length(eigen(TT)$value)
eigenValues <- eigen(TT/(nn-1))$value
for (i in 1:sizeEigenTT) 
{
        if (eigenValues[i] < 0) {
    print(paste("There are only", numberObsAfter,"nonmissing observations out of a possible", numberObsBefore ,"observations."))
    stop("The TSS matrix is indefinite. There must be too many missing values. The index cannot be calculated.")
        } 
}
```

And I think the root cause of this error is the negative eigenvalues that seep in when the number of clusters is very high, i.e. the `max.nc` is high. So to solve the problem, you must look at your data. See if it got more columns then rows. Remove missing values,  check for issues like collinearity & multicollinearity, variance, covariance etc.

For the other error, `invalid clustering method`, look at the source code of the method [here](https://github.com/cran/NbClust/blob/master/R/NbClust.R). Look at line number `168, 169` in the given link. You are getting this error message because the clustering method is empty. `if (is.na(method))
         stop("invalid clustering method")`